# Exporting the filtered data from a django table

Tags: django-filter, django-import-export

I am using django-filter and django-import-export. I can build an HTML table and filter it using django-filter just fine, but I want the user to be able to export the filtered table, not the whole table. (That is, this is not through the admin feature.)

I *suspect* the issue is I have one view for the list itself, but the export is in another view, and I can't seem to pass the filtered queryset to the export view, and I can't figure out how to do the export and filter on the same view. They're both GET requests. I feel like I'm missing something very very basic here.

In my app/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .filters import RoleFilter
from .models import Role
from .resources import RoleResource

from tablib import Dataset

def role_list(request):
    """list the roles and filter appropriately"""
    f = RoleFilter(request.GET, queryset=Role.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'app/rolelist.html', {'filter': f})

def export_filtered_roles(request):
    """export to csv"""
    f = RoleFilter(request.GET, queryset=Role.objects.all())
    dataset = RoleResource.export(f)
    response = HttpResponse(dataset.csv, content_type="text/csv")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="roles.csv"'
    return response
```

I can't seem to make the connection. This version of the code gives me an error: RoleFilter object has no attribute 'before-export'. I get the same error if I use `dataset = RoleResource.export(f.qs)`.

Any suggestions as to how I can tie the filter to the export view?

---

Additional Information: Here's the template I'm using

```
<form method="get" action=".">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Filter"/>
</form>

<table>... loops through filter.qs ...</table>
<a href="{% url 'roleexport' %}">Export Roles</a>
```

This is why I think there's a disconnect between the Form object and the export feature. Can I somehow control the export from the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a hack, but it works. All I had to do was change the link in my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'roleexport' %}?{{request.GET.urlencode}}">Export Roles</a>
```

This works for the filtered and unfiltered lists.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line looks incorrect:

```
dataset = RoleResource.export(f)
```

You are calling `export()` on the class, and not an instance of the class.

What happens if you try:

```
dataset = RoleResource().export(f.qs)
```

As you say, `export()` takes a queryset as an argument, not a filter, so ensure you are passing the qs from the filter, and not the filter itself.

Comment: It doesn't give me an error but it gives me the full dataset, not the filtered set from the table.

Comment: @Matthew Hegarty. Help me here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67015477/how-to-pass-a-filter-from-a-dropdown-into-django-import-export-view